# Kernel panic - not syncing: softlockup: hung tasks

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb, panic, armv6

I am currently experiencing a kernel panic with one of my code. The kernel panic seem to be not with null pointer dereferencing, since I have got the below hint,

**Kernel panic - not syncing: softlockup: hung tasks**

Using GDB, I decoded the backtrace and the crash points to below line,

**for (i = 0; i <= list->maxlimit; i++),** where **i** is short int and  **packet->maxlimit** is integer(32 bit)

On further disassembling the function, I found the crash points to the below ARM instruction

**uxtb w4,w4**

which is nothing but variable promotion before comparing (i <= list->maxlimit).

I would like to know whether kernel panic occurs with variable promotion or my interpretation is wrong. Also please let me know what softlockup kernel panic means and how to proceed with that kind of kernel panics?

Thanks in advance!

Thanks, Santhosh

Comment: what can we say except that _list_ is an invalid address ?

Comment: I don't see the string `list->maxlimit` in the kernel sources? Is this your own code?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Ya this is my own code...the crash is pointing to variable promotion...something wierdo

Comment: @bruno  list holds a valid valid, otherwise I would have observed a crash while dereferencing itself...but the crash points to variable promotion of i

Comment: @bruno List holds a valid address, otherwise I would have observed a crashed while dereferncing itself...the crash points at variable promotion of i

Comment: @santhosh Probably the code is running into an infinite loop or something like that, which is why the kernel detects a soft lockup (basically, an unexpected delay).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer oh, if that is the case, then why does it point to variable promotion. That's confusing me...i am not able to move further on this....could you please let me know how could we approach this issue?

Comment: @santhosh I think soft lockups are reported asynchronously, interrupting whatever the CPU is doing at this point. You can add some `printks` (with loop iteration counts, and also in loops) to determine how the code executes and check that it matches your expectations.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Thanks for your inputs...but I came across this issue only once...Dont know flooding debugs would help...

Comment: What is the value of maxlimit? If it is integer type and larger than short type the index i may overflow back to 0 before reaching the maxlimit hence your process is stuck by the for loop...  the softlockup error can happen for various reasons. It is likely your process is holding a lock and get stuck in the for loop and cause starvation on other tasks that are waiting for the same lock

Comment: @luke Ya maxlimit is integer and index i is short int